# Ordering while Splitting and Appending the same column vertically in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe like below,

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
|key     |colname1|column3      |
+--------+--------+-------------+
|   key1 |     2  |         23  |
|   key2 |     4  |         11  |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

I want to split a column and do some operation on one of the dataframe and append the column

Before any operation on df1:

```
 df1                      df2
+--------+--------+      -------------+
|key     |colname1|      |column3      |
+--------+--------+      +-------------+
|   key1 |     2  |      |         23  |
|   key2 |     4  |      |         11  |
+--------+--------+      |-------------+
```

After an operation on df1 (Operation is colname1*2):

```
 df1                      df2
+--------+--------+      -------------+
|key     |colname1|      |column3      |
+--------+--------+      +-------------+
|   key1 |     4  |      |         23  |
|   key2 |     8  |      |         11  |
+--------+--------+      |-------------+
```

If I append the df2  back to df1 does Spark gaurentees that the sequence stays the same? if not, Is there any way I can achieve this?

Expected df:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
|key     |colname1|column3      |
+--------+--------+-------------+
|   key1 |     4  |         23  |
|   key2 |     8  |         11  |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: You will need some join key through which you can join back. So while spitting keep your `key` column in new dataset as well so you can join back. And For most of the operation you dont need to split dataset. Splitting dataset will rebuild it from beginning unless you `cache`/`checkpoint`. I think if you share your usecase then we can help to achieve same without splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not guarantee that the sequence will stay the same, As data is partitioned across workers and depending on the transformation & action applied over the dataframe data could shuffle.

To perform above task splitting is not required.

```
//Input CSV
key,c1,c2
key1,2,23
key2,4,11

val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("split_data.csv")
val mdf = df.withColumn("c1", col("c1") * 2)
mdf.show(10)
+----+---+---+
| key| c1| c2|
+----+---+---+
|key1|4.0| 23|
|key2|8.0| 11|
+----+---+---+
```

However, if still split is required then a join operation has to be performed using a key.

```
val df1 = df.select("key", "c1").withColumn("c1", col("c1") * 2)
val df2 = df.select("key", "c2")
val df3 = df1.join(df2 , "key")
df3.show(10)
+----+---+---+
| key| c1| c2|
+----+---+---+
|key1|4.0| 23|
|key2|8.0| 11|
+----+---+---+
```

Generally, Join operation is a little heavy, so the optimized way to do this would be the first approach.